# Gmail Contextual Gadgets and OpenID Authentication steps

Tags: openid, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I'm trying to understand the correct sequence of steps followed by Gmail when loading and authenticating a contextual gadget. One of the reasons (there are others) is that I want to know whether I can make the gadget manifest behind a Open ID authentication so that only authenticated users will be able to pull the gadget in to Gmail.

I haven't seen any documentation on this anywhere.
Here's how I think it works... (where mysite.com is an openID relying party).

User: *clicks on a mail in Gmail inbox*
Gmail: Load email. Retrieve gadget manifest from mysite.com/gadgets/gadget.xml
MySite: You need to be authenticated to access gadgets/gadget.xml
Gmail: Here's the user's OpenID
MySite: Here's gadgets/gadget.xml
Gmail: *"paints" the gadget contents on the context area of the email*

Please correct me if this is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think the answer to my question is here:
http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/best_practices.html#gadget_sso

According to this, there's no implicit OpenID authentication. It's your responsibility to make it happen by using osapi.http.get.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is how it works:

1. Admin installs your app at that point you can use SSO to get the admin's OpenID
2. if you want to use 2-legged OAuth to get say all
       of the user's on the domain you can do that too (although I have
   not
       gotten that to work yet)
3. When a user in that domain loads
       your
           gadget you can use: osapi.http.get which will append the
           open_social_id to the request to your server.
4. now you
       have
           the
               opensocialid you can check if you have a user in your
   system
           with
               that open_social_id, if not then you can do through the
   same
           OpenId
               auth process you did in step 1 for the admin, but this
   time
       you
               relate the Open Social Id with the OpenId you receive in
   the
           auth
               process
5. now anytime that user loads your gadget you
       can
           look
               up
                   their open social id and determine that they have
       already
           been
                   authorized.